# C# mass build windows services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I basically want to build 10 copies of a windows service that was coded.  The only change I want to make to the code is to change the service name from MyService1 to Myservice2 ect...

Is there a simple way to simply build those and export them to twenty different directories?

Comment: Aside from the obvious, what are you trying to achieve by having 10 copies?

Comment: I want to run the same application simultaneously 10 times.  And i'm not sure how to run 10 instances using 1 service.

Comment: Have you looked into multi-threading?

Comment: No, and to be honest, I would been a lot of help to produce this app as such, also, because of the source of data exceptions could occur almost anywhere, and I can't have 1 single point of failure.

Comment: This is, as others have hinted, absolutely the wrong solution. Try editing your question to ask about the thing you actually want to accomplish, rather than your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem, as noted in the comments, would be to use multiple threads to spin off the same logic in parallel with one another.  There are many ways to achieve this, through background workers, thread pools, and simple one-off threads.  For instance, you could have the following setup:

```
...  [In your main thread]

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  new Thread(()=> { DoSomething(); });
  // Once spun off, the application will not block here.  It will continue
  // the next iteration, while DoSomething does something. 
}

...

private void DoSomething()
{
    // Execute some logic
}
```

This would spin off 10 threads with your applications logic, executing `DoSomething()`.  They would all run parallel to each other.  However, this is by no means the only way to do it, and in this example, you aren't managing the threads.  You're simply instantiating them and forgetting about them.  It would really benefit you to read up on threading -- as this would solve your multiple-project issues.

Comment: Awesome simple example, however, how would i tell my service to spin up a new thread everytime it went below 10?

Comment: @Mike You'd need to manage your threads. You could do this using a thread pool. You could also manage it yourself, by incrementing and decrementing a shared variable, and responding appropriately.  This is really up to you and the architecture you want to go forward with.  What I have above it the simplest of threading examples and isn't a canned solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, there are probably better ways to address the problem.
( What is the problem you are solving? )

As for creating multiple services with different names, have you considered the `sc` command?

This gets run from the commandline as:

```
sc create MyService1 binPath= c:\foo.exe
sc create MyService2 binPath= c:\foo.exe
```